# Using JavaScript in Ant

Tags: javascript, ant

I am having issues using the `<script>` tag in Ant and I am hoping someone can help.  I want to use JavaScript in my Ant `build.xml`.  Something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="java" default="main" basedir=".">
  <target name="main">
    <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
 println("hello, world")
    ]]> </script>
  </target>
</project>*
```

Unfortunately this only displays and error:

> build.xml:4: Could not create task or type of type: script.

I have located the required jar file (`js.jar`) for this to work and moved it to `ANT_HOME/lib`, but I am still stuck as of how to get this to work.

Comment: Which version of Ant are you using? Run "ant -version" on the command line. Also, which OS are you running?

Comment: ANT is version 1.6.5 on a red hat 5 u 8 OS

Comment: What is your java version ? See my comment on the answer of Chad

Comment: also 2 problems => missing ';' after println.. and trailing '*' after closing project tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `js.jar`, you need to add `bsf.jar` and `commons-logging-*.jar` to ANT_HOME/lib. In your Ant distribution, there is a file named `docs/manual/install.html`. The **Library Dependencies** section of this HTML file documents where you can download these files.

`println` isn't supported in JavaScript. Instead, use the following:

```
<project name="jsTest" default="main">
  <target name="main">
    <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
        var echo = jsTest.createTask("echo");
        echo.setMessage("hello, world");
        echo.perform();
    ]]> </script>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: you don't need js.jar and bsf.jar anymore, as jdk >= 6 ships with a builtin Javascript Scripting Engine based on Rhino 1.6R2

Comment: why not simply use print("hello, world"); instead ?

Comment: [Ant 1.6.5 doesn't work with JDK 
1.6's JavaScript engine](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/201011.mbox/%3COF9BBC5C85.102E2E03-ON652577DE.0032ADE4-652577DE.0035CFFE@tcs.com%3E). If user2286073 upgrades to Ant 1.7 or later, then all of these issues will be resolved.

Comment: you're are right, using ant 165 will produce java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/bsf/BSFException

Answer (score 3):

You can also instantiate and use Java classes in Javascript as available via Rhino(JRE pre 1.8) or Nashorn(JRE 1.8+) when you need to.

```
<script language="javascript">
  with(new JavaImporter(java.lang, java.io)){
    System.out.println("hello, world");// <--!!!
  }
</script>
```

You may create and use JavaScript functions of your own.

```
<script language="javascript">
  with(new JavaImporter(java.lang, java.io)){
    var fun = function(a,b){
      System.out.println(a+b);
    };
    fun(1,2);
  }
</script>
```

Code above prints

```
3.0
```

Loops, recursion and everything you've been dreaming about... except strong type checking:-)

Answer (score 1):

Beside the two syntax errors - missing ';' after println.. and trailing '*' after closing project tag - you should upgrade your ant installation to a version >= 1.7.x in conjunction with jdk >= 6 to be able to use the builtin javascript engine.
When using jdk >=6 the use of println is no problem, see :

```
import javax.script.*;
public class ExecuteJS {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
 engine.eval("print('Line1')");
 engine.eval("println('Line2')");
 engine.eval("print('Line3')");
 engine.eval("println('Line4')");
 }
}
```

output :

```
Line1Line2
Line3Line4
```

and

```
<project>
 <script language="javascript">
  println("hello, world");
 </script>
</project>
```

But further testing with Ant 1.9.0 / Win7 (my linux box is down right now) / jdk1.7.0_21 revealed some oddities :

```
<project>
 <script language="javascript">
  println("hello, world");
 </script>
</project>
```

works

```
<project default="foo">
<target name="foo"> 
 <script language="javascript">
  println("hello, world");
 </script>
</target>
</project>
```

works also

```
<project name="whatever" default="foo">
<target name="foo"> 
 <script language="javascript">
  println("hello, world");
 </script>
</target>
</project>
```

works also, whereas

```
<project name="java" default="foo">
<target name="foo"> 
 <script language="javascript">
  println("hello, world");
 </script>
</target>
</project>
```

results in

```
BUILD FAILED
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "PrintWriter" from undefined (print#8) in print at line number 8
```

Strange !?
 Seems like a bug, so finally upgrade ant >= 1.7.x and jdk >= 1.6 and
 don't use 'java' in name attribute of project :-)